# How to pass parameter to Maven project from Jenkins

Tags: java, macos, maven, jenkins, parameter-passing

I want to learn how to pass parameter to Maven project from Jenkins.
Firstly I chose *General* configuration in Jenkins and click *This project is parameterized* then:

Name: `my_parameter`

Choices: `desktop`,
`ipad`,
`tablet`

Source Code Management → Git → Repositories → Repository URL: *I wrote Git repo link, it was OK.*

Build → Execute shell → Command: `mvn test -DdeviceType=$my_parameter`

My Maven Project has a parameter named `String device`.

```
    String device;

    public static DesiredCapabilities caps=null;


    @BeforeSuite
    public void initializeDriver() throws MalformedURLException{
        device=System.getenv("deviceType");
        System.out.println("device type: "+ device);

        if (device.contains("ipad")) {
            caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
            caps.setCapability("browserName", "iPad");
            caps.setCapability("platform", "MAC");
            caps.setCapability("device", "iPad Mini 4");
            caps.setCapability("browserstack.local", "true");
            caps.setCapability("browserstack.debug", "true");
            caps.setCapability("safariAllowPopups", "true");
            caps.setCapability("acceptSslCerts", "true");
            caps.setCapability("browserstack.autoWait", "0");
            caps.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", "true");

            driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), caps);
        }
```

Then build with parameters on Jenkins:

```
 $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/j9/gyf9715j0hs32m4gd8h_gw4m55zss4 /T/hudson7304038831620598368.sh
 + mvn test -DdeviceType=desktop
 [INFO] Scanning for projects...
 device type: null[0m
```

Why does device type return `null`? What's wrong?
Thanks for your helps...

Comment: You haven't considered yet using a Jenkins _Maven project_ type supplied by the [Jenkins Maven Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/maven-plugin/), have you?

Answer (score 4):

**In Jenkins**

In Job configuration, click on "***This project is parameterised***" and add a parameter (String param like the example below):

[image: Job parameterised]

Add parameter with name (PARAM_NAME_TEST) and a default value that will be used if the parameter is not set

[image: Parameter setting]

In the build section under "***Goals and options***", pass the parameter value with maven command like (defining property using **mvn -D**):

```
clean test -DPARAM_NAME_TEST=${PARAM_NAME_TEST}
```

[image: Build section]

**In Maven Project**

Get the parameter value using:

```
 String paramValue = System.getProperty("PARAM_NAME_TEST");
```

Comment: If I am not looking to use the value inside the code, but rather inside my pom.xml, could I directly use it or do I still need to pass using `-DPARAM_NAME_TEST=${PARAM_NAME_TEST}`

Answer (score 1):

Well, at the least, the "`-D`" commmand-line parameter to "`mvn`" sets "system properties", not "environment variables".  Instead of calling "`System.getenv()`", call "`System.getProperty()`".

Comment: i've tried  device=System.getProperty("deviceType");
System.out.println("device type: "+ device);
There is no difference. device type returns null

Comment: This is because system props provided to mvn don't translate to system properties available to surefire-based unit tests.  If you still want to use system properties (preferable to env vars for this), look at http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html for how to set surefire system properties.

Answer (score -1):

I finally found answer by trying. But I'm not sure whether that's the best way for solution. I chose:

**BUILD** → **Invoke top-level Maven targets**

Goals: `test`

But important issue is parameter name in Jenkins must be same name your Maven projects variable name.

```
device=System.getenv("deviceType");
```

Then build with parameters on Jenkins it works!

Answer (score -1):

For someone trying to pass variable from Jenkins pipeline to local pom.xml file., what you can do is pass the argument through mvn clean install console command.

in your POM.xml

```
    <properties>
       <maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>
    </properties>
```

use this variable setting up plugin

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
    <configuration>
     <skipTests>${maven.test.skip}</skipTests>
     <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now we will set up Jenkins side of things:

What I did here is created a boolean build parameter value SKIP_JUNIT_TEST that can control the value passed through arguments.

After creating build parameter, in your pipeline code you can pass the argument like this:

```
sh 'mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=${SKIP_JUNIT_TEST}'
```

here maven.test.skip is the variable I have set in pom.xml

Comment: The [`surefire:test`](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#skip) goal recognizes the property `maven.test.skip` by itself ("_<skip> ... **User Property**: maven.test.skip_"). You don't have to declare an extra `<build><plugin>...` just for that. Simply `<properties><maven.test.skip>...` is sufficient. Furthermore, you don't have to declare both `<skip>` and `<skipTests>`. The former is a superset of the latter, i.e. it doesn't even compile tests. And, the OP neither mentioned nor tagged the question with _pipeline_ and apparently used the UI configuration.